# Splitting Flex configuration files into sub-smaller files?

Tags: apache-flex, configuration, blazeds, lcds

Have anyone tried to slit WEB-INF/flex/remoting-config.xml and WEB-INF/flex/data-management-config.xml into multiple sub files (like remoting1.xml, remoting2.xml..etc.) ?

If yes please let me know how you do that. I tried, googled but failed. Thanks

Comment: I dont think you can do it, unless you are using spring-blazeds integration libraries, where you can split the context files into several files.

Comment: @Zeus : no I can't. Gave up :(